# How to use a ContextMenu UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a user control like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UserControls.MyContextMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
        ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.ContextMenu>
</UserControl>
```

My question is: how do I use that context menu for something like a data grid:

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="{usercontrols:MyContextMenu}"
```

Unfortunately that does not work because the specified value is incorrect and expected a `ContextMenu`.

**Note:** I need to reuse my context menu in several places, so I have put it in its own file. Also, I need to be able to listen to `OnContextMenuOpening` events, because the menu upon opening needs to do some work regarding the menu and the event is not fired for the context menu sadly: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/353112/contextmenu-opening-event-doesnt-fire-properly

> "ContextMenu itself is a FrameworkElement derived class, but this
>   event will not be raised from the context menu being opened as a
>   source. The event is raised from the element that "owns" the context
>   menu as a property and is only raised when a user attempts to open a
>   context menu in the UI."

This event problem is the reason I have put the menu for a user control -- so that the user control can get the event and do the work.

**Update:** I tried to have it as a root element and extend the context menu:

[image]

And code-behind:

[image]

But I'm getting: `ContextMenu cannot have a logical or visual parent`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of how you call your UserControl, it is not a ContextMenu. You would have to derive from [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx) instead of UserControl:

```
<ContextMenu x:Class="MyApp.MyContextMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
    ...
</ContextMenu>
```

and

```
public partial class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    public MyContextMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But why would you do that at all?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. However, yours will not work, because "ContextMenu cannot have a logical or visual parent". You cannot define `ContextMenu` as the root element.

Comment: Does not work for me. It complains that `ContextMenu` cannot have a logical or visual parent. I.e., it means that context menus can only be used for UI element's ContextMenu property values, not as elements. This also has another problem: I cannot listen to `OnContextMenuOpening` events.

Comment: I do derive from the ContextMenu. And even if it worked, I still need to listen to `OnContextMenuOpening` event and the event is not fired for the context menu -- only for the elements that hold the menu, and in this scenario there is no one holding it.

Comment: Don't know where that parent should come from. If you look at my XAML and code, you'll see a class derived from ContextMenu. No UserControl at all! This can be used in any place where a ContextMenu is expected. And of course you have to use it somewhere, otherwise it would make no sense at all.

Comment: 1) I need to reuse the context menu in several places and 2) I need to listen to `OnContextMenuOpening` event and do some work regarding the menu that gets opened. The sad fact is that the menu never gets the event fired -- only the placement target. See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/353112/contextmenu-opening-event-doesnt-fire-properly

Comment: Why don't you override [ContextMenu.OnOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.onopened), or is that too late?

Comment: how do you get rid of the `cannot have a logical or visual parent`? I have the code exactly as you described. `ContextMenu` is the root element, followed by `MenuItem`s, the code behind contains a class extending `ContextMenu` user control.

Comment: I guess you still have ContextMenu contained in a UserControl, at least that is how i can reproduce the error you mention. The <ContextMenu>...</ContextMenu> is the **top-level** XAML element. Nothing around it.

Comment: Looks exactly like mine. Don't know what's going on there. Did you rebuild your project?

Comment: Okay, it seems to build and run and everything works fine! I still get this error though. I think it might be a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have created a similar User control with 'ContextMenu' as the root element instead of user control and when I use `<DataGrid ContextMenu="{usercontrols:MyContextMenu}"` I am getting expected type 'ContextMenu' error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Try to defineit like:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="DgContextMenu">
      ...
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

and after use it like

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="{StaticResource DgContextMenu}
```

*Should* work.

Comment: What do you mean -- I can't define a key for it because it's a user control and not a resource or can I?

Comment: @rFactor: if you want to use **exactly** that one of user control, if yes, you can define menu like a static resource and use it on boh controls.

Comment: Seems like an obtuse way of doing it when you could just define `DataGrid.ContextMenu` rather than `DataGrid.Resources` and specifying the resource as the `ContextMenu` property.